# Is it possible to see only community wiki questions (as if it were a tag?)

Tags: feature-request, support, comments, community-wiki, filtering

Hi! I'm wondering, is it somehow possible to filter to only view community wiki questions, as if community-wiki were a tag? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is possible using the search:

```
wiki:1 views:0
```

(the "`views:0`" part is to make sure that we're only searching questions, not answers)

Comment: Thanks! I also found the search tips page just now, that will help me.